# Can I add and ad after I've published an android app to the play store?

Tags: ads

I am going to publish and android app. Is it possible to add on ads in a later update or do I have to include them when I first release it? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policies/usage, not programming.

Comment: sorry for the topic. I have now changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also possible to include them later. Usually you have to include the advertiser's library into your app and put some code snippets into your code in order to display the ads. All this is possible whenever you want.

A much more interesting point is how your users will react on this late advertisment placing. In most cases apps do not have that many users when they are relatively new. So each and every user's negative reaction upon this can give you negative ratings which will give your app a worse ranking in the app store which will lead to less downloads in the future. People tend to accept things when they are given but do not like it when something was better before.

Finally you have to decide whether you would take the risk to provoke negative reactions or invest one or two more hours into your application before you publish it.